# spring jms listener change acknowadge type to not auto

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

OK I am using spring jms listener and currently I am using the default acknowledge type - auto so the message is consumed before ti is imported/processed. How I can change this type to something that later using this listener I can manually confirm when this message is processed and shall be removed

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the acknowledge attribute of the listener-container to client. Consult reference [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html) for more info.

```
<listener-container acknowledge="client"> 
</listener-container>
```